# jenkins send files or execute commands over ssh trouble

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I'm using jenkins with publish over ssh plugin. I'm only executing scripts to stop, clean a start services. When I'm executing script start through putty, it starts services successfully and I can leave putty with services running at back-end. However when I execute this script through Publish over SSH plugin, some services aren't started but I can see in log that they were started by script.

Can somebody give me an idea what can be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`<service start>`

run

`BUILD_ID=dontKillMe <service start>`

Jenkins kills all spawned processes from a build, with command above you can detach service from build. More details you'll find in jenkins wiki under [process tree killer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller)